# Qt normal status bar not showing after temporary status

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, statusbar

Normal status message -these are always shown by an application unless a temporary message is shown. This is what I know about normal status message. So using these code on my constructor

```
ui.statusbar->showMessage("Temp message", 3000); // ui is the Ui::AutoGenHeaderForForm
QLabel *label = new QLabel;
ui.statusBar->addWidget(label);
label->setText("hello world");
```

I get that, when I run my project I get the status **Temp message** for 3 sec. Then I don't get the **hello world** back. Should the **hello world** come automatically after 3 sec in the position of **Temp message** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the code you show is in the constructor of your main window, the problem might be due to events not being properly processed because the event loop is not yet started at the time of the main window creation.

Try to execute the `showMessage` in a "delayed initialization" slot, e.g.

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel;
ui.statusBar->addWidget(label);
label->setText("hello world");
QTimer::singleShot ( 0, this, SLOT(delayedInit() );

void MainWindow::delayedInit()
{
    ui.statusbar->showMessage("Temp message", 3000); // ui is the Ui::AutoGenHeaderForForm
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to do it without QStatusBar::addPermanentWidget.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstatusbar.html#addWidget) is pretty clear:

> The widget is located to the far left of the first permanent widget
>   (see addPermanentWidget()) and may be obscured by temporary messages.